# Is it possible to use libcu++ with scala-native for GPU programming?

Tags: scala-native

I am trying to build a super-optimizer in scala native and to perform better I would like to have GPU support. is this possible with some GPU programming library for C or C++?

Answer (score 0):

- Due to Scala Native having interoperability with C language but not with C++, NVIDIA's libcu++ would need to have C-language wrapper written around it.
- A better fit might be CUDA C, also from NVIDIA.  https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-c-cpp
- The only Scala Native GPU-related library that I know of is OpenGL-related, which is not as direct exposure of the GPU's capabilities as you are seeking.  https://github.com/regb/scalanative-graphics-bindings